# GlassFish clustering + EJB lookup

Tags: glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

We have Glassfish cluster which has two instances.

On this cluster one my EJB application  is deployed and running.

Now I have another EJB-Timer-application which I want to deploy on Glassfish server(domain) not on cluster then I want to access the cluster's EJB. AS per my understanding EJB timer could not deployed on a cluster because it could be run on both the instances of cluster.

What are the possible ways to access it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can actually deploy EJB timers on a cluster. They will only execute on one instance. At startup, each @Scheduled bean is assigned in a round-robin manner to an instance. If an instance fails, the timers will fail-over to the next healthy instance.

Remember to follow the setup procedure for EJB timers as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beahw.html. In short, you need to specify an XA datasource for the timers database instead of using the default embedded one.

We are running several @Scheduled beans in a Glassfish clustered production environment.

Comment: while doing lookup for EJB in Glassfish clustered  environment, i'm getting lookup issue but same code is working fine in standalone instance. do i need to change the jndi.properties file.